# Why does importing NLTK in python gives error

Tags: nlp, nltk, token

I upgraded NLTK to latest version and while import nltk, I get the following error

```
import nltk
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 210
    print("[Trained Unigram tagger:", end=" ")
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I commented this line but then another error. python version used is 2.7

Answer (score 1):

NLTK requires Python >= 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, or 3.8.
Upgrade your python version and it will work fine.

1. create an environment:

   `conda create -n myenv python=3.6`

   `source activate myenv`
2. pip install nltk
3. finally:

   `import nltk`

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Uninstall the current nltk package
Step2: Change the root directory or the file path, it would've been altered from its default route.
Step3 : Install the Nltk package again

Hope this helps :)
I had a similar problem, it got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you are using python2.But nltk dropped support to python 2 in latest versions of it.Try to use older versions of nltk in which it supports python 2 and I found out that nltk 3.0 version supports python 2.

You can download that version by command

```
pip install nltk==3.0
```

You can change the version number which is 3.0 in the above mentioned case and can install suitable version whichever you feel like working.

I have faced similar problem and after installing previous versions it worked for me.